# Mac Terminal clang error linker command fail

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, clang

I try to compile and build this [code](https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate) in my Mac OS. I try this following cmd.

```
cd ideviceactivate
make
sudo make install
```

In terminal when I tried with `make` it gets following error.

```
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: you don't have librt installed where it can find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)